# Good software to dictionary or brute force attack IIS/ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, security, forms-authentication

I am looking for something that takes an IIS/ASP.NET website that uses forms authentication and repeatedly tries to login, either with all possible passwords or with passwords from a dictionary.

I can probably write something up, but I wondered if there was anything publicly available that would be better implemented.

Comment: Care to explain why you need to attack a web site?

Comment: @adam : maybe he want to use it against a a web application that he is developing ...

Comment: I probably should have stated it, but I am responsible for the security of said web site.

Comment: I think that trying to brute-force your own website as a security measure is low-reward while placing a heavy burden on your server. Isn't it better to establish a password policy that prevents users from selecting dictionary-crackable passwords?  Also, if you plan to use 'all possible passwords' that says little about the the security of your server as eventually the attack will succeed no matter what.

Comment: This is an important question.  You must test the security of your systems before its too late.

Answer (score 1):

For online brute forcing of login systems I recommend using [THC-Hydra](http://freeworld.thc.org/thc-hydra/).  I always use this tool in my penetration tests.  By contrast if you have a password hash or a salted password hash then you should use [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) to break it offline which is much faster.

After 3 failed logins you should prompt that ip address with a captcha like [reCaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the built-in ASP.NET membership provider, there's a property you can set called `passwordAttemptThreshold`. After a certain number of attempts the account will automatically be locked. While you can still be brute-force attacked, the chances of an account being compromised within the `passwordAttemptThreshold` is sufficiently low. Also, you can enforce a password policy with the membership provider as well, which really makes brute-force attacks less likely.

Granted, this doesn't answer your exact question, however you may still find it more prudent to simply prevent brute-force attacks from happening in the first place. Whatever brute-force library you find, there will always be a better one out there - and the good ones probably aren't even available as they are no doubt a closely-guarded secret of real hackers.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of attacking the website from the outside, I would recommend taking the hashes and cracking them offline.

A better approach is to make a password policy on the site so you don't have to do this. Password cracking is tough, and unnecessary in most situations